# Futter Driver Automation Testing not working due upgrade in version of Flutter Driver

Tags: appium, flutter-test, appium-android, automation-testing, appium-java

Can some one help where our app is not showing in Appium inspector and even not working for Automation code in intellij after upgrade to Flutter driver version 3.0

getting error: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: I was on latest version of Flutter. but downgraded to Flutter 2.10.4 to get it working with Appium 1.22.2. My flutter installation step is now `RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --branch 2.10.4 --single-branch`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, Upgrade to appium-flutter-driver v1.7.0 with Appium 2 (2.0.0-beta.43 is the latest when I'm posting this)

Start Appium server using the command `appium -p 4726 --base-path /wd/hub` as sometimes starting server with default port was not working fine!

If you are not on Appium 2 already, check this guide for migration, I found it helpful

https://www.headspin.io/blog/migrating-to-appium-2-0-part-1-capability-prefixes
https://www.headspin.io/blog/installing-appium-2-0-and-the-driver-and-plugins-cli